# how to pull a specific node from a json data library, and return its value

Tags: python, json, api, decode

i have a script that pulls json data from an api, and i want it to then after pulling said data, decode and pick which tags to store into a db. right now i just need to get the script to return specific called upon values. this is what the script looks like, before me trying to decode it.

```
import requests
def call():
payload = {'apikey':'945e8e8499474b7e8d2bc17d87191bce', 'zip' : '47120'}
bas_url = 'http://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators/locate'
r = requests.get(bas_url, params = payload)
grab = r.json()
return grab
```

---

this is what i was told to try to get those specific tags returned

```
return [{key: value for key, value in result.items() if key in ("twitter_id", "office")} for result in jsonData]
```

but that returns errors. any suggestions?

'results': [{'twitter_id': 'RepToddYoung', 'ocd_id': 'ocd-division/country:us/state:in/cd:9', 'oc_email': 'Rep.Toddyoung@opencongress.org', 'middle_name': 'C.', 'votesmart_id': 120345, 'first_name': 'Todd', 'youtube_id': 'RepToddYoung', 'last_name': 'Young', 'bioguide_id': 'Y000064', 'district': 9, 'nickname': None, 'office': '1007 Longworth House Office Building', 'term_start': '2015-01-06', 'thomas_id': '02019', 'party': 'R', 'in_office': True, 'title': 'Rep', 'govtrack_id': '412428', 'crp_id': 'N00030670', 'term_end': '2017-01-03', 'chamber': 'house', 'state_name': 'Indiana', 'fax': '202-226-6866', 'phone': '202-225-5315', 'gender': 'M', 'fec_ids': ['H0IN09070'], 'state': 'IN', 'website': 'http://toddyoung.house.gov', 'name_suffix': None, 'icpsr_id': 21133, 'facebook_id': '186203844738421', 'contact_form': 'https://toddyoungforms.house.gov/give-me-your-opinion', 'birthday': '1972-08-24'}, {'twitter_id': 'SenDonnelly', 'ocd_id': 'ocd-division/country:us/state:in', 'oc_email': 'Sen.Donnelly@opencongress.org', 'middle_name': None, 'lis_id': 'S356', 'first_name': 'Joe', 'youtube_id': 'sendonnelly', 'last_name': 'Donnelly', 'bioguide_id': 'D000607', 'district': None, 'nickname': None, 'office': '720 Hart Senate Office Building', 'state_rank': 'junior', 'thomas_id': '01850', 'term_start': '2013-01-03', 'party': 'D', 'in_office': True, 'title': 'Sen', 'govtrack_id': '412205', 'crp_id': 'N00026586', 'term_end': '2019-01-03', 'chamber': 'senate', 'state_name': 'Indiana', 'fax': '202-225-6798', 'phone': '202-224-4814', 'gender': 'M', 'senate_class': 1, 'fec_ids': ['H4IN02101', 'S2IN00091'], 'state': 'IN', 'votesmart_id': 34212, 'website': 'http://www.donnelly.senate.gov', 'name_suffix': None, 'icpsr_id': 20717, 'facebook_id': '168059529893610', 'contact_form': 'http://www.donnelly.senate.gov/contact/email-joe', 'birthday': '1955-09-28'}, {'twitter_id': 'SenDanCoats', 'ocd_id': 'ocd-division/country:us/state:in', 'oc_email': 'Sen.Coats@opencongress.org', 'middle_name': 'Ray', 'lis_id': 'S212', 'first_name': 'Daniel', 'youtube_id': 'SenatorCoats', 'last_name': 'Coats', 'bioguide_id': 'C000542', 'district': None, 'nickname': None, 'office': '493 Russell Senate Office Building', 'state_rank': 'senior', 'thomas_id': '00209', 'term_start': '2011-01-05', 'party': 'R', 'in_office': True, 'title': 'Sen', 'govtrack_id': '402675', 'crp_id': 'N00003845', 'term_end': '2017-01-03', 'chamber': 'senate', 'state_name': 'Indiana', 'fax': '202-228-1820', 'phone': '202-224-5623', 'gender': 'M', 'senate_class': 3, 'fec_ids': ['S0IN00053'], 'state': 'IN', 'votesmart_id': 53291, 'website': 'http://www.coats.senate.gov', 'name_suffix': None, 'icpsr_id': 14806, 'facebook_id': '180671148633644', 'contact_form': 'http://www.coats.senate.gov/contact/', 'birthday': '1943-05-16'}]}

Comment: Post an example of the decoded JSON. (That is, add `print(grab)` to your program and copy-paste a sample of that into your question.)

Comment: Please stop posting the same questions again and again. If you do not stop, action will be taken. This is for your own good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your json looks something like `[{}, {}, {}]` from what you posted.  i.e. `grab` is a python list of dictionaries.

Try this?

```
get_nodes = lambda x : {"twitter_id" : x.get("twitter_id", None), 
    "office" : x.get("office", None)}

def call():
    ... whatever you had before ...
    return map(get_nodes, grab)
```

Also, if you wanted your original answer to work, you need to add an "else" value.  In the future, I would recommend posting what kind of error you're getting rather than just saying "this threw an error".

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/brad/Documents/congress.py", line 10, in call
    grab = r.json()
  File "", line 808, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/y", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: any resource for me to learn about this scenario would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your code is crashing on `r.json()`.  If the data sample you posted in your edit is what you're getting, then it isn't valid json (missing a curly brace at the very beginning).  Can you post the exact output of `r.text`?

Comment: im sorry, this is the VERY ORIGINAL script to grab the json doc. ill add it to the post, so you can see it in format

Comment: you misunderstood what i wanted to do i think. node isn't the correct term. i want to be able to return whatever values(keywords in the json dictionaries) i name from the json file, and return its value IE. 
'results': [{'twitter_id': 'RepToddYoung',